# WP8 PhotoCamera source, being stretched when rotating the VideoBrush

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, camera

I'm making an app, that uses the camera to scan qr codes. The app is using the portrait orientation only. However the VideoBrush is in landscape mode on the portrait page. The image shows what I mean below:
[image]

Obviously my computer screen is not that wide, the video is being stretched :/
So, right now I'm using `UniformToFill`, which in theory should cut off parts not matching the aspect ratio. They are not :(

How do I get it to display the right aspect ratio without stretching the preview?
This is my xaml:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="_cameraRect">
     <Rectangle.Fill>
           <VideoBrush x:Name="_previewVideo" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                 <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                      <CompositeTransform x:Name="vTransform" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Rotation="90"/>
                 </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
           </VideoBrush>
     </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work as you want:

```
<Canvas.Background>
    <VideoBrush x:Name="viewfinderBrush" Stretch="None" />
</Canvas.Background>
```